# Logging in with PHP

Tags: php

**Full Disclosure:** This is homework.

I wouldn't bring this here, but I really have no idea what's going on, the server error reporting I'm using is bringing up nada and I'm getting absolutely no output what so ever from the script. I know this isn't how one would ideally do this kind of operation.

**The Form**

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <img class="featuredImg" id="logo" src="Images/ZombieBitLogo.png">
  <hr>
  <form id="form-signin" class="form-signin" action="login.php" method="POST">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Come on in</h2>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="user" required="" autofocus="">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="pass" required="">
    <button id="signin" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" name="action" value="login">Sign in</button>
  </form>

  <form class="form-signin" action="login.php" method="GET">
    <button id="signout" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" name="action" value="logout">Sign out</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**The PHP**

```
<?php
echo( "hello");
if( !session_start() ){
    echo( "Error 312: Zombie chewed through a cable." );
    exit;
}//endif

    $user = empty( $_POST[ "user" ]) ? '' : $_POST[ "user" ];
    $pass = empty( $_POST[ "pass" ]) ? '' : $_POST[ "pass" ];

    echo( $user );
    echo( $pass );

$loggedIn = empty( $_SESSION[ "loggedin" ]) ? false : $_SESSION[ "loggedin" ];

if( $loggedIn ){
    header( "Location: order.php" );
    exit;
}//endif

$action = empty( $_POST[ "action" ]) ? '' : $_POST[ "action" ];

if( $action == "login" ){
    handle_login();
}else{
    login_form();
}//endel

function handle_login(){
    $user = empty( $_POST[ "user" ]) ? '' : $_POST[ "user" ];
    $pass = empty( $_POST[ "pass" ]) ? '' : $_POST[ "pass" ];

    if( $user == "test" && $pass == "pass" ){
        $_SESSION[ "loggedin" ] = $username;
        header( "Location: order.php" );
        exit;
    }else{
        header( "Location: log.html" );
        require "log.html";
    }//endel        
}//endfn

function login_form(){
    $user = "";
    $error = "";
    require "log.html";
}//endfn
?>
```

The echos along the way are just to see the values, none of them print on my end.

**Edit:** I see now that this was a pretty bad place to post this and a poor question.

Comment: For starters, there should be no *output* (ie `echo`) before `session_start()`

Comment: Is the php code part of a file named login.php found in the same directory as the form? Same file would work too

Comment: Also, your `require` after `header` isn't going to do anything good. Always `exit` after a *Location* header

Comment: So what *server error reporting* are you using? You should have a minimum of `display_errors = On` and `error_reporting = E_ALL` in your `php.ini` file

Comment: Yes, in login.php. I'm not sure about the error reporting, was told by the instructor to type 'httperrors' into terminal, nothing happens much like when you run something that gets stuck in an infinite loop. I've verified in the past that this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty difficult to help out the code since it has many problems, but this might give you an idea if you look at it written more cleanly

```
<?php

session_start();

if(!empty($_POST))
{
    if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass']))
    {
        if($_POST['user'] == 'user' && $_POST['pass'] == 'pass')
        {
            $_SESSION[ "loggedin" ] = $_POST['user'];
            header( "Location: order.php" );
            exit;    
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Oops!';  // better to place in variable and set in desired location
        }
    }
?>
 HTML STUFF

 THE FORM MUST BE "POST" AND NOT "GET"

<input id="signin" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" name="action" value="Sign in" />



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use the $_POST superglobal with a GET request.

Your form method attribute is set to "GET" and your PHP document is using the $_POST superglobal.  That won't work..

Change your form method attribute.

```
<form class="form-signin" action="login.php" method="POST">
```

Furthermore, NEVER EVER EVER use a GET request for a Login form.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That's a good point, but the first submit button is within the first form, which is POST.